# Installing emulator for flutter on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

Im on Windows 10 and have been trying for days to get an emulator working with Android Studio and have followed every tutorial religiously with no luck. I have set up the Nexus 6 emulation which starts just fine as shown in my image below but the devices dropdown always says `no devices`. So frustrated with this and nothing is mentioned about this issue anywhere. I also get an error `unable to locate adb` everytime I start the virtual device. What is causing the issue and what are the proper steps for setting up to avoid these issues

[image]

Comment: there are 2 folders (`tools` and `platform-tools`) in the Android SDK folder; did you add their paths to the `environment variables`?

Comment: @MuhammadAdam Awesome that worked! Thanks a lot, didn't see this anywhere in the docs or any beginner videos not sure why it isnt mentioned. I still get the `unable to locate adb` error but I guess that can be ignored since everything seems to be working fine. Will this adb error affect me later on, maybe on deployment?

Comment: it's fine I guess and maybe it'll be gone after restarting windows

Comment: Ok cool thats good