# Unable to locate ADB Android studio, flutter

Tags: android-studio, adb

I know there is already post about this, but none seems to work for me. Android studio unable to locate ADB. I checked my adb.exe exists in the path folder. I have deleted my McAfee anti virus as well following the advice from before, but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The virtual device api was Android 10+ (30), and I just added another virtual device (Android 10, 30). I don't see the error any longer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you were facing, I have Researched the Whole Internet but found nothing useful. So, I somehow figured out the problem and fixed it, The problem is at

app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

Whenever we create a new project due to some reason the Module SDK is not set up automatically. Thus the ADB manager was throwing an error 'Unable to locate AVD', which is not that fatal as the error/warning is not stopping us from launching /starting the emulator, but it is so annoying to see that pop-up box. So here is my simple and quick fix.

Solution:

Click on the project folder, tap the dropdown icon just beside it.

Now Navigate to the path below.

> android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

Now Click on the file GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java to open it.

Once it is open, At the Top you will notice a bar that says 'Module SDK is not defined',

Now right against it, you will also see a hyper-text named 'Setup SDK', Just Click on it.

That will open a Pop-up Box with the title 'Select project SDK'.

Now select the Android Platform API and then click OK. After that being done Restart your IDE.

Your Problem will be Solved. And you will also notice that Emulator Opens up way faster than before.

NOTE:

The Above Steps has to be performed with every new flutter project.

I have already answered the problem here before.

Follow this link to see the pictures and step by step process.

[Android Studio - launch emulator AVD - "unable to locate adb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468046/android-studio-launch-emulator-avd-unable-to-locate-adb)