# "Unable to locate adb" using Android Studio on Windows 10 to develop Flutter apps

Tags: android-studio, flutter, adb

Android Studio upgraded to version 4.0.1, and now I get a "Unable to locate adb" message when trying to launch an Android emulator image from the AVD manager, in order to run/debug a Flutter app. I have tried all the obvious things, e.g. checked to see that there is an adb.exe image at .../AppDate/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools. I have even tried de-installing completely and did a clean install of everything from scratch. I have plenty of disk space, anti-virus has not quarantined it. Interesting, if I start a native Android app (e.g. "basic activity"), then the message goes away and the image starts OK

Answer (score 4):

[Android Studio - launch emulator AVD - "unable to locate adb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468046/android-studio-launch-emulator-avd-unable-to-locate-adb)

Visit the above link to get solution in detailed way with pictures.

I had the same issue as you were facing, I have Researched the Whole Internet but found nothing useful. So, I somehow figured out the problem and fixed it, The problem is at

app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

Whenever we create a new project due to some reason the Module SDK is not set up automatically. Thus the ADB manager was throwing an error 'Unable to locate AVD', which is not that fatal as the error/warning is not stopping us from launching /starting the emulator, but it is so annoying to see that pop-up box. So here is my simple and quick fix.

Solution:

Click on the project folder, tap the dropdown icon just beside it.

Now Navigate to the path below.

> android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

Now Click on the file GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java to open it.

Once it is open, At the Top you will notice a bar that says 'Module SDK is not defined',

Now right against it, you will also see a hyper-text named 'Setup SDK', Just Click on it.

That will open a Pop-up Box with the title 'Select project SDK'.

Now select the Android Platform API and then click OK. After that being done Restart your IDE.

Your Problem will be Solved. And you will also notice that Emulator Opens up way faster than before.

NOTE:

The Above Steps has to be performed with every new flutter project.

I have already answered to your question before to Read more and understand in detail with pictures just visit the link
[Android Studio - launch emulator AVD - "unable to locate adb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468046/android-studio-launch-emulator-avd-unable-to-locate-adb)

Comment: Many thanks, this worked. Annoying that it has to be done for every flutter project!

Comment: Yes, and you find my answer helpful kindly accept my answer by clicking the check mark . Have a good day !